# Extract pixels data from GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I'm completely unfamiliar with GIS type files, I'm kind of outside the field, but I have an algorithm to test that processes pixels from such files.

In this situation, I'm looking for a way to convert a GeoTIFF file (I have several of these on disk) into one that contains no metadata, just the pixel values of all bands themselves. How can this be done?

And is there any way to extract information about how the data is stored in the file, in terms of whether it is BSQ or BI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what kind of format you want to use (ASCII? Binary?). There are some standard formats that are quite simple to convert to using the GDAL command line utilities. For example to convert a GeoTIFF file `input.tif` into an ASCII file:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif output.asc
```

If you want a binary format (probably, if your files are large enough), you can use the ENVI format, it's just a binary file with the metadata stored in a sidecar `.hdr` file (the format is described [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/envi.html)). If you GeoTIFFs have several bands, you can select how you want them stored (either all bands for pixel 1, all bands for pixel 2... or all pixels for band 1, all pixels for band 2).

```
gdal_translate -of ENVI input.tif output.img
```

You can also do the same thing in Python (if you want to loop over files):

```py
from osgeo import gdal

input_f = "input.tif"
ret = gdal.Translate("output.img", "input.tif", format="ENVI")
ret = None
# or...
ret = gdal.Translate("output.asc", "input.tif", format="XYZ")
ret = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Raster to point tool should give you the data extraction you need. It can then be exported as a table or csv when complete.

Comment: Is it possible in QGIS? I have just installed this tool. I'm looking for an option, but it's hard to figure out especially since I don't know the terminology used for such files.